# Python: ignore filenotfound and other errors in pandas/python code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exception

I have wrote a code which has basically the following structure:

Step 1: import libraries

Step 2: read multiple input files

```
>>>os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Input\\Daily'

>>>df_delhi = pd.read_excel("Delhi.xlsx")
>>>df_mea = pd.read_excel("MEA.xlsx",sheet_name='MTD NSV_Volumes',usecols ='B:D', skiprows=3)
```

Step 3: calculations on each file

Step 4: output in excel file.

I have a condition here. out of 20 odd files, if any one file is missing, i need to ignore that and move ahead with the code. Also i need to ignore the calculations from that file which come later on in the code.

How do i achieve this?

Not sure if any code is required to be pasted here since its just basic file read and calculations

Comment: reading multiple input files, is it from a different folder or is there any text file that contains list of files to be read.

Comment: its just a single folder with multiple files.

Comment: So, ur reading files using ```os.listdir``` ?

Comment: updated my question, does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Exceptions (official Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). By expecting and catching a `FileNotFoundError` you could neatly ignore that file, and only work on files which you find.

Answer (score 0):

Look's like u need to loop over a directory and read the file's avilable in it.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# each file get's different argument's while reading..
file_params = {
    "Delhi.xlsx": {},
    "MEA.xlsx": {"sheet_name": 'MTD NSV_Volumes', 'usecols': 'B:D'},
}

data = {}
for file_ in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Input\\Daily'):
    data[file_.replace(".xlsx", "")] = pd.read_excel(file_, **file_params.get(file_, {}))

# dataframe's contained inside dict.
# data['Delhi'], data['MEA']....
```